# Set ActionBar on ViewPager embed within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm trying to set an ActionBar on a ViewPager embed within a fragment, which is updated when i use a DrawerLayout.
The problem is, when i call the `final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();`, it sets the ActionBar to my main fragment instead of my ViewPager (I know the problem come from the getActivity() which returns the mainActivity), and so it ain't destroyed when the fragment change, and when i switch back to the fragment embing the ViewPager, the ActionBar tabs are re-added to the activity...

Here is my code sample :

FragmentHolder (Activity that holds the main Fragment + the NavigationDrawer) :

```
public class FragmentHolder extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    // navigation drawer
    navigationArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_array);
    navigationDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ...
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case INDEXDRAWERMAIN:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentWindow, new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
                navigationDrawer.closeDrawers();
                break;
            case INDEXDRAWERTOP:
                holder.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentWindow, new TopActivityFragment()).commit();
                navigationDrawer.closeDrawers();
                break;
    ...
}
```

TopActivityFragment :

```
public class TopActivityFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_top_fragment, container, false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    topFragmentPagerAdapter = new TopFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(topFragmentPagerAdapter);

    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    // Here is the problem
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    ....
}
```

activity_top_fragment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- Possible alternative to the action bar...
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" />
    -->

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml (XML for FragmentHolder) :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout class="MainActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentWindow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank you for your future help ;-)

Edit : After a bit of working i found out that the ActionBar i call from TopFragmentActivity is in fact the FragmentHolder ActionBar, which is also used by my NavigationDrawer. So now what i'm trying to do is delete the two tabs that i add within TopActivityFragment. I succedded in doin that, but it let a blank space in my ActionBar and i can't figure how to automatically resize my Actionbar so it clear the space it doesn't use. I tried calling notifydataSetChange on my Adapter but it crashes and i'm almost sure it's beacuse it can't be reached in the onDestroy....

TopActivityFragment :

in the onCreateView :

```
actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Départs").setTabListener(tabListener),0);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Arrivées").setTabListener(tabListener),1);
```

int the overidded onDestroyView

```
actionBar.removeAllTabs();
```

Comment: are you using custom action bar?

Comment: I don't think so, i use 'import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;'

Comment: did u try custom action bar

Comment: No, but i don't think that really matters, does it? or am I wrong? If so please explain me

Comment: u r calling the action bar in "TopActivityFragment  " . so it will get it in that activity.

Comment: Yes, i know, but ain't there a way to call it on the ViewPager directly? Or to remove it from the Fragment when i switch it?